# Primary Key Function in ArangoDB

Tags: mysql, key, primary-key, arangodb

I am new in learning with ArangoDB, and I was wondering if there is an equivalent of mySQL's *primary key* function in ArangoDB's AQL

Answer (score 0):

`Primary key` automatically present on `_key` attribute.

You can refer [this](https://www.arangodb.com/why-arangodb/sql-aql-comparison/) link for more.